# Linearly independent vectors with null components

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations

I have two vectors $~A = (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4, \cdots, a_n)~$ and $~B = (b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4, \cdots, b_n)~$ which are linearly independent, (both compoenents are different from zero)

I want to know if:

$~A = (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4, \cdots, a_n)~$ will be linearly independent to $~B'=(b_1,b_2, 0,0,0,\cdots,0)~$ ?

where only $~b_1,~b_2~$ are non null and the rest of the elements is equal to zero.

I need to have a linearly independent vector to $~A~$ where only the first elements are non-null, and the rest is null.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried examples?  Suppose, say, that $A=(b_1,b_2,0,\cdots)$?

Comment: Thank you , but I'm assuming that A is different from B' (since A does not have null components)

Comment: "Since $A$ does not have null components"  Where was this stated?  Regardless, the end result that you seem to be reaching for is that if $A=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ where each of $a_i$ is nonzero and $B=(b_1,b_2,0,\dots,0)$ with $b_1,b_2\neq 0$ then $A$ and $B$ will be trivially linearly independent.  In fact, in general if $A$ has component $a_i$ nonzero and $B$ has component $b_i$ equal to zero (and neither is the zero vector), then $A$ and $B$ are trivially linearly independent.  This can be seen easily by the definition.

Comment: After all, if you were to suppose that $\alpha A + \beta B = 0$, the in particular the $i$'th component you have $\alpha a_i + \beta b_i = \alpha a_i + 0$ which if were equal to zero would imply that $\alpha$ must be zero.  But then $0 + \beta B$ equalling zero would require that $\beta=0$, thus proving they are linearly independent.

Comment: JMoravitz Thank you for your answer this is so helpful, and since A and B' are linearly independent, A+B' should be also linearly independent to A?

Comment: Yes, if $u,v$ are linearly independent, then $u,u+v$ are linearly independent.  This is regardless of any other specifics about $u,v$ beyond the fact that they are linearly independent.  We don't care how many zero components they have or where they are located.

Comment: Thank you so much JMoravitz !